# For the article page of news app, I’d prefer to put the photograph along the article text to the right side, rather than centrally

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

**How I implement this type of layout for the app. I need exactly this type of layout for the application.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look this library. It is useful in your case.

https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="News Titlessssssss ssssssssssssssssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```